# Initial blockchain sync stuck on block 237158

Tags: blockchain, synchronization

Stuck on block 237158. Rebooting doesn't work.

Do I need to start from scratch?

```
admin@raspberry2bit:~ $ sudo tail -f /mnt/ext/bitcoin/debug.log
2020-10-26T08:48:30Z Loading addresses from DNS seed dnsseed.bitcoin.dashjr.org
2020-10-26T08:48:30Z Loading addresses from DNS seed seed.btc.petertodd.org
2020-10-26T08:48:30Z Loading addresses from DNS seed seed.bitcoin.sipa.be
2020-10-26T08:48:41Z Loading addresses from DNS seed dnsseed.bluematt.me
2020-10-26T08:48:41Z Loading addresses from DNS seed dnsseed.emzy.de
2020-10-26T08:48:41Z Loading addresses from DNS seed seed.bitcoinstats.com
2020-10-26T08:48:52Z Loading addresses from DNS seed seed.bitcoin.jonasschnelli.ch
2020-10-26T08:48:52Z Loading addresses from DNS seed seed.bitcoin.sprovoost.nl
2020-10-26T08:48:52Z 0 addresses found from DNS seeds
2020-10-26T08:48:52Z dnsseed thread exit

admin@raspberry2bit:~ $ systemctl status bitcoind.service
● bitcoind.service - Bitcoin daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/bitcoind.service; enabled; vendor preset: 
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-10-26 16:47:23 CST; 21min ago
  Process: 672 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/bitcoind -daemon -pid=/run/bitcoind/bitco
 Main PID: 680 (bitcoind)
    Tasks: 18 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bitcoind.service
           └─680 /usr/local/bin/bitcoind -daemon -pid=/run/bitcoind/bitcoind.pid 

admin@raspberry2bit:~ $ bitcoin-cli getblockchaininfo
{
  "chain": "main",
  "blocks": 237158,
  "headers": 654013,
  "bestblockhash": "00000000000000fdd7d1d53f13da7654e80a645a7ea09a5763b62ff6355fe61b",
  "difficulty": 11187257.46136079,
  "mediantime": 1369114906,
  "verificationprogress": 0.03152660781442522,
  "initialblockdownload": true,
  "chainwork": "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000043f4c527c060c0911f",
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [bitcoind in testnet is not synchronizing](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/23462/bitcoind-in-testnet-is-not-synchronizing) ... your log message  *"0 addresses found from DNS seeds"* is what you need to fix